# Design a table around matrix table.

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design

So I have a database that is for selling products. The orders tables hold's the customer's order info like shipping province and Shipping method:

```
+--------------------+----+
|       order        |    |
+--------------------+----+
| someOtherInfo      |    |
| shippingMethodID   | fk |
| shippingProvinceID | fk | 
| basePrice          |    |
+--------------------+----+
```

Basically what's happen now is we have a base price for shipping that's based on the Province and Shipping Method. I need to now add that base price for shipping to my orders table and the fact that base price for shipping is a Matrix table or 2d array where col(shipping Method) + Row(Province) = baseCost is throwing me off on how to implement it. I never had to deal with this so Don't even know what to look up.

Example of what the matrix looks like:

```
+--------+----+----+----+-----+
|        | BC | AB | SK | etc |
+--------+----+----+----+-----+
| ground |  9 |  9 |  9 |     |  
| Air    | 15 | 21 | 21 |     |  
| etc    |    |    |    |     |  
+--------+----+----+----+-----+
```

Comment: Please post current data of orders and not just its schema. On cursory look, you may need Access' [crosstab query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8).

Comment: seems like you need to normalize the structures then queries will be straight forward.

Comment: Isn't this just a lookup on the province field where you shipping ID matches?  Try a dlookup.